# Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2008, data-binding, dataset

my error is simple but for me it is hard to fix it because my knowledge is not good . which is when i Enter the record by clicking the Addbutton of AddStudent record then the record that i deleted like record StudentID = 1, FirstName =Raju ,LastName=Abbasi

After Delete it again and press save Change even After that when i again try to use the ID=1 means enter the Record with ID=1 that i have been deleted and record the StudentID=1 ,FirstName =Ram ,LastName=Rakish .Then error is occur which is

```
    private static SqlDataAdapter CreateSutdentDataAdapter()
           {

               string gettSQL = "SELECT * FROM Student";

               string insertSQL = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Student ON;INSERT INTO Student(StudentID, FirstName,LastName,Gender,GPA,MyImage)" +
                   "VALUES (@StudentID,@FirstName,@LastName,@Gender,@GPA,@MyImage);SET IDENTITY_INSERT Student OFF";
              string updateSQL = "UPDATE Student SET  FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName ,Gender=@Gender, MyImage=@MyImage," +
                " GPA=@GPA WHERE StudentID=@StudentID";
               string deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM Student WHERE StudentID=@StudentID";

               SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

               dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(gettSQL, ConnectionManager.GetConnection());

               dataAdapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, ConnectionManager.GetConnection());

               dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@StudentID", SqlDbType.Int).SourceColumn = "StudentID";
               dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar,25 ).SourceColumn = "FirstName";
               dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25 ).SourceColumn = "LastName";
               dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar ,1).SourceColumn = "Gender";
               dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@GPA", SqlDbType.Float ).SourceColumn = "GPA";
               dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyImage", SqlDbType.VarBinary).SourceColumn = "MyImage";

               dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, ConnectionManager.GetConnection());
               dataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@StudentID", SqlDbType.Int).SourceColumn = "StudentID";
               dataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar,25 ).SourceColumn = "FirstName";
               dataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25 ).SourceColumn = "LastName";
               dataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar ,1).SourceColumn = "Gender";
               dataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@GPA", SqlDbType.Float ).SourceColumn = "GPA";
               dataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyImage", SqlDbType.VarBinary).SourceColumn = "MyImage";
               dataAdapter.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand(deleteSQL, ConnectionManager.GetConnection());
               dataAdapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("@StudentID", SqlDbType.Int).SourceColumn = "StudentID";

               return dataAdapter;

           }

       private static void DefinestudentTableSchema(DataTable table)
       {
           DataColumn StudentIDColumn = table.Columns.Add("StudentID", typeof(string));
           StudentIDColumn.AllowDBNull = false;

           table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { StudentIDColumn };

           DataColumn StudentFirstName = table.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
           StudentFirstName.MaxLength = 150;
           DataColumn StudentLastName = table.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
           StudentLastName.MaxLength = 150;
           DataColumn StudentGender = table.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(string ));

          DataColumn StudentGPA = table.Columns.Add("GPA", typeof(string ));
          DataColumn StudentImage = table.Columns.Add("MyImage", typeof(Byte[]));

       }
       private static DataSet CreateStudentTrackerDataSet()
       {
           DataSet StudentTrackerDataSet = new DataSet();
           DataTable StudentTable = StudentTrackerDataSet.Tables.Add("Student");
           DefinestudentTableSchema(StudentTable);
           return StudentTrackerDataSet;
       }

       public static DataSet GetData()
       { 
           DataSet StudentTrakerDataSet = CreateStudentTrackerDataSet();
           StudentTrakerDataSet.EnforceConstraints = false;
           StudentDataAdapter.Fill(StudentTrakerDataSet.Tables["Student"]);

           StudentTrakerDataSet.EnforceConstraints = true;
           return StudentTrakerDataSet;
       }

        public AddModifyStudentRecords(DataSet ds, DataRow row)
        {
public static void SaveData(ref DataSet changesDataSet)
       {
           DataSet addedDataSet = changesDataSet.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
           if (addedDataSet != null)
           {
               StudentDataAdapter.Update(addedDataSet.Tables["Student"]);
               changesDataSet.Merge(addedDataSet); // Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints
           }
           DataSet modifiedDataSet = changesDataSet.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
           if (modifiedDataSet != null)
           {
               StudentDataAdapter.Update(modifiedDataSet.Tables["Student"]);
               changesDataSet.Merge(modifiedDataSet);
           }
           DataSet deletedDataSet = changesDataSet.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted);
           if (deletedDataSet != null)
           {
               StudentDataAdapter.Update(deletedDataSet.Tables["Student"]);
             deletedDataSet.Merge(deletedDataSet);
           }
```

here is my Addmodifyform logic for add the StudentID

```
public partial class AddModifyStudentRecords : Form
    { 

        DataSet StudentTrackerDataSet;
        DataRow currentRow;


        public AddModifyStudentRecords()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public AddModifyStudentRecords(DataSet ds)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StudentTrackerDataSet = ds;
            currentRow = null;
        }
    public AddModifyStudentRecords(DataSet ds, DataRow row) 
    {
    InitializeComponent(); 
    StudentTrackerDataSet = ds; 
    currentRow = row;
    textBox1.Text =currentRow["StudentID"] .ToString(); 
    textBox2.Text = currentRow["FirstName"].ToString(); 
    textBox4.Text = currentRow["LastName"].ToString(); 
    textBox3.Text = currentRow["Gender"].ToString(); 
    textBox5.Text = currentRow["GPA"].ToString(); 
    txtBrowseFile.Text = currentRow["MyImage"].ToString (); 
    byte[] data = (byte[])currentRow ["MyImage"]; 
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data); 
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms); 
    string StudentID = textBox1.Text.ToString(); 
    string StudentFirstName = textBox2.Text.ToString(); 
    string StudentLastName = textBox4.Text.ToString(); 
    string Gender = textBox3.Text.ToString(); 
    string GPA = textBox5.Text.ToString(); 
    Image MyImage = pictureBox1.Image; 
    DataTable table = StudentTrackerDataSet.Tables["Student"]; 
    if (currentRow == null) {
    currentRow = table.NewRow(); 
    currentRow["StudentID"] = textBox1.Text.ToString(); 
    table.Rows.Add(currentRow ); 
    } 
    currentRow .BeginEdit();
    currentRow ["StudentID" ]=StudentID ; 
    currentRow["FirstName"] = StudentFirstName; 
    currentRow["LastName"] = StudentLastName; 
    currentRow["Gender"] = Gender; 
    currentRow["GPA"] = GPA; 
    currentRow["MyImage"] = convertToByte(txtBrowseFile.Text); 
    currentRow.EndEdit(); 
    Close();
   }
```

public partial class AditStudent : Form
        {
            // Creat the Class variabl Dataset to track the Student
            private DataSet StudentTrackerDataset;

```
        public AditStudent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataGridView1.DataError += DataGridView1_DataError;
            StudentTrackerDataset = ProjectOfSchool.DataAccessLayer.DAC.GetData();

            DataTable StudentTable = StudentTrackerDataset.Tables["Student"];

            dataGridView1.DataSource = StudentTable;
            //StudentTable.Columns["ID"].AutoIncrement = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                if (dataGridView1.Columns[i] is DataGridViewImageColumn)
                {
                    ((DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[i]).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
                    break;
                }
        }
        private void DataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
        {

            string message = string.Format("Error in {0} columan in row {1}:{2}", e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, e.Exception.Message);

            MessageBox.Show(message, "Data Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddModifyStudentRecords AddStudent = new AddModifyStudentRecords(StudentTrackerDataset);
            AddStudent.ShowDialog();
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object id = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["StudentID"].Value;
            DataRow StudentRow = StudentTrackerDataset.Tables["Student"].Rows.Find(id);
            AddModifyStudentRecords modifyStudent = new AddModifyStudentRecords(StudentTrackerDataset, StudentRow);
            modifyStudent.ShowDialog();
        }
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure", "Delete Current Row", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                object id = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["StudentID"].Value;
                DataRow currentRow = StudentTrackerDataset.Tables["Student"].Rows.Find(id);
                currentRow.Delete();
            }
        }
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!StudentTrackerDataset.HasChanges())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There are no Change to Save ", "Save Changes", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    DataSet changesDateSet = StudentTrackerDataset.GetChanges();
                    ProjectOfSchool.DataAccessLayer.DAC.SaveData(ref changesDateSet);
                    StudentTrackerDataset.Merge(DAC.GetData());
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Save Successfully.", "Save Changes");
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Not Saved:" + ex.Message, "Save Changes", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
            }
        }
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!StudentTrackerDataset.HasChanges())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There are no Changes to Save.", "Save Changes", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else
            {
                DialogResult result = MessageBox .Show ("Are you Sure?","Reject Changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes )
                {
                    StudentTrackerDataset.RejectChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

And When i terminate the program and re execute the program then i saw that StudntID=1 is also save to Database with ID=1

or When i Delete the StudentID =1 and press save Change after press save Change when i also Terminate the program and re exicute the program and after that when i Enter the StudentID =1 Then no error is occur

And other way without termination is to Delete the record StudentID1 but when you Add the Student record but not Add the StudentID=1 But add the StudentID other then 1 in this case error is also not happend . Dear Sherik I have been solve my other error but i have still error which is in my Tittle So please responding me for this error And i re edited my code also So  please replay me Thanks

I have record in my Database which have following Datatype as

StudentID=INT,

FirstName=VarChar,

LastName=VarChar,

Gender=Varchar,

GPA=Float,

MyImage=Vabinary (MAX)

Or may be Datarow fail to Delete the record or Update the record. I don't know please tell me and thanks to reply me and I am waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message seems to indicate that you are hitting a Primary Key constraint. 
I would suggest that you first stop allowing the user to enter the Student ID field. Let it be generated as an auto increment key in whatever database you are using. In Access, it is called AutoNumber.

Once you have done that, re test and post the results.

Comment: Respectable Shrieks my program is to manually enter the StudentID if i will do it then error is occur if not then i have to pass the StudentID in textbox1.text of form AddstudentRecord and i don't know how to pass the StudentID in textbox1.text when click the Addbutton of the AddStudent form . And also tell me how to generate the auto increment key

Comment: here is my Addmodifyform logic for add the StudentID public AddModifyStudentRecords(DataSet ds, DataRow row)
InitializeComponent();
StudentTrackerDataSet = ds;
textBox1.Text =currentRow["StudentID"] .ToString();
textBox2.Text = currentRow["FirstName"].ToString();
textBox4.Text = currentRow["LastName"].ToString();
textBox3.Text = currentRow["Gender"].ToString();
textBox5.Text = currentRow["GPA"].ToString();
txtBrowseFile.Text = currentRow["MyImage"].ToString ();
byte[] data = (byte[])currentRow ["MyImage"];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

Comment: and also this  string StudentID = textBox1.Text.ToString();
string StudentFirstName = textBox2.Text.ToString();
string StudentLastName = textBox4.Text.ToString();
string Gender = textBox3.Text.ToString();
string  GPA = textBox5.Text.ToString();
Image  MyImage = pictureBox1.Image;
DataTable table = StudentTrackerDataSet.Tables["Student"];
if (currentRow == null)
{

Comment: currentRow = table.NewRow();
currentRow["StudentID"] = textBox1.Text.ToString();
table.Rows.Add(currentRow );
}
currentRow .BeginEdit();currentRow ["StudentID" ]=StudentID ; 
currentRow["FirstName"] = StudentFirstName;
currentRow["LastName"] = StudentLastName;
currentRow["Gender"] = Gender;
currentRow["GPA"] = GPA;
currentRow["MyImage"] = convertToByte(txtBrowseFile.Text);        
currentRow.EndEdit();
Close(); yes it is hard to read it but if you will try to look at then you can understand that what is my actual problem that why i can solve it due to my logic in program and thanks to replay

Comment: I am waiting for your replay please replay me so that i can solve my problem thanks

Comment: I have edited your question to put the code in there. Can you please separate the methods of AddNew and Modify? currently, it is too much noise to make much sense to me.

Comment: I Edited my post for you now i think you can understand my programming logic that when i click the Addbutton of form Addstudent then i will add the record in AddmodifyStudenRecord Form and by clicking the Button2 means Ok button then Record is shown in Datagridview and By clicking SaveChange button of the Form AddStudent Button Form Record is Save button it is manually enter of  StudentID not AutoIncrementing StudentID or i don't know really what is actual happening my program logic. I am new in this feild and self learner also so poor in family can't helped from othere So please help me Thank